# Function parameter parsing if the type can vary

Tags: python

I have a function that can be called with either a boolean `onoff` or a dictionary `request`. If `onoff` comes *directly* as a parameter, it can be `True`, `False` or `None`. If it comes from `request` dictionary, then `request["onoff"]` can be either an int or a string (it comes from a HTTP API request; note: it is already sanitized).

```py
def func(onoff=None, request=None):
    if request is not None:
        onoff = request.get("onoff")
    if onoff is not None:
        onoff = bool(int(onoff))   # works but it seems not very explicit
        if onoff:
            print("Turn On")
        else:
            print("Turn Off")
    else:
        print("onoff is None, so no modification")

func()
func(onoff=True)                   # True
func(request={"onoff": 1})         # True
func(request={"onoff": "1"})       # True
func(onoff=False)                  # False
func(request={"onoff": 0})         # False
func(request={"onoff": "0"})       # False
```

Is there a way to avoid this custom `bool(int(onoff))` and have a general way to handle this situation?

Comment: Why not parse it immediately in `if request is not None:` so that `onoff` **always** is True, False or None, instead of just putting whatever `request.get("onoff")` contains without thought?

Comment: @matszwecja would you have an example code? NB: I need to keep the `None` case, that's important!

Comment: `if request is not None: onoff = bool(int(request.get("onoff")))` and then you can remove `onoff = bool(int(onoff))` in following if.

Comment: @matszwecja This doesn't work, it would remove the possibility for onoff to remain `None` :) I already did this mistake ;)

Comment: Can it come from `request["onoff"]` as `None`?

Comment: @matszwecja We can have `func(request={"other_param": 1})` so `onoff` should stay `None`.

Comment: Are those 2 signatures mutually exclusive? Is `func(onoff=False, request={"onoff": "1"})` call ever possible?

Comment: @matszwecja Thanks for your comments! Yes mutually exclusive. `func(onoff=False, request={"onoff": "1"})` not possible.

Comment: Why not extract a function that you call directly and _only_ accepts the optional boolean, rather than trying to deal with both cases in one? That way the request handler has a single responsibility of parsing the request dictionary and delegating the actual functionality.

Comment: In that case I'd split those into two functions, as jonrsharpe suggests. As Python Zen says, there should be only 1 obvious way to do something. Make one function that requests interacts with, which parses the arguments into a consistent form and another that handles the rest of the logic and expects `bool` (or None) argument only.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the edit but the fact `other_param` can be set is maybe important to emphasize that `onoff` can be mising...

Comment: The `bool()` adds no value; using `if` directly on the `int` has the exact same efect.

Comment: and if you _did_ use pydantic to coerce your arguments into `TypedDict('onoff_bool_dict', {'onoff': bool}) | TypedDict('request_dict', {'request': TypedDict('onoff_int_dict', {'onoff': int}))`, you'd have something that does the casting for you and generates a proper error message when the input doesn't meet one of the valid forms.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. The function takes (according to the question) either a value that could be None or boolean OR a dictionary. So, why not define it as taking just one argument, use isinstance(arg, dict) and go from there? Also, bool(int(onoff)) isn't very helpful if onoff=="0"

Comment: @CtrlZ there can be several params like `func(onoff=True, other_param=False)` <=> `func(request={"onoff": "1", "other_param": "0"})`.

Comment: @Basj You might want to re-read the first sentence in the question. They key word being "or"

Answer (score 1):

As [Python Zen](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) says: *"There should be one - and preferably only one - obvious way to do it."*
According to that, you shouldn't have two ways of calling your function, that are doing the same thing, yet come into conflict with each other. Instead, create one function that is offered by the interface to requests and parses possibly str or int arguments e.g.:

```
def request_func(request):
    onoff = request.get("onoff")
    if onoff is not None:
        onoff = bool(int(onoff))
    func(onoff, request['other_param'])
```

and another that can be called directly, which always expects `bool` arguments:

```
def func(onoff=None, other_param=None):
    if onoff is not None:
        if onoff:
            print("Turn On")
        else:
            print("Turn Off")
    else:
        print("onoff is None, so no modification")
```

This way each function has a single, specific signature and you don't risk having conflicting arguments passed using both ways at the same time.

```
func(onoff=True)                           # True
request_func(request={"onoff": 1})         # True
request_func(request={"onoff": "1"})       # True
func(onoff=False)                          # False
request_func(request={"onoff": 0})         # False
request_func(request={"onoff": "0"})       # False
```

Comment: This would be perfect, but it would need to convert each function (with deals both "direct" call and "request" call) to 2 functions. Maybe in a future refactoring. Do you see an elegant way in 1 single function?

Comment: Any "direct" calls do not require changes, if you didn't pass `request` to them. My initial sentence explains why, inherently, there is no elegant way to do it in 1 function - arguments conflict one with another.

Answer (score -2):

In `bool(int(onoff))`, `bool` is not really necessary because the if statement automatically converts it into a boolean value.

Also since the only `False` integer is `0` you can easily do

```
onoff = onoff != "0"
```

But this doesn't check if onoff is an integer or not; it just returns `True` if it's not `0`

Comment: `onoff = onoff != "0"` is True for `onoff` equal to `0`.